# What's the Subreddit extension to get subscriber numbers?

Tags: xml, reddit

So I'm trying to pull subscriber numbers to subreddits and I can't seem to figure out where the xml is with that data. I've seen numerous sites that have subreddits and the number of subscribers. Anyone know the extension?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that information is only available in JSON, not XML: [For example.](http://www.reddit.com/r/babyelephantgifs/about.json)

```
subscribers: 49295
```

Here is the description of that API path [in the documentation.](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_r_%7Bsubreddit%7D_about.json) You'll also find everything you need about the whole API by exploring this documentation.